# Как вписать круг в рамку

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Использую круг для картинки в бутстрап:

```
<img src="..." alt="..." class="img-circle">
```

Но, так как картинка белая, она сливается с фоном, можно ли как-то нарисовать рамку вокруг нее?

Comment: Вы имеете в виду вписать круг в рамку?

Comment: Да, человек снизу уже оветил.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Bootstrap 2:**

```
<img class="img-circle img-polaroid" ... />
```

**Bootstrap 3:**

```
<img class="img-circle img-thumbnail" ... />
```